# why does my zoomToExtent in OpenLayers not work when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

in [this](http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~s0825955/thomson_kml.html) map I have added a line of code to make it zoom to the vector layer:

```
map.zoomToExtent(vector_Layer.getDataExtent());
```

This zooms in to the maximum zoom at the point in the Gulf of Guinea where the equator meets the Greenwich meridian. Its not supposed to zoom here, its should show Scotland.

I've passed the same bit of code in the console in Chrome and that works fine. Perhaps, it wont work until after the page has loaded. Does anyone know why its not working properly when the page loads and does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right; occasionally scripts need to have the page elements loaded (and present, in the `DOM`) before they can act on them. I would start by trying one of these two approaches:

1. Move your JS `<script>` tags to the bottom of the page, and out of the `head`. Put them just before the closing `body` tag, and see if that works. This way, your page has time to load (this is a very common practice).
2. Alternatively, you can call this function in an `onLoad` event. You can read about how to use it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp).

UPDATE:

Have a look at the following resources, if the above solutions don't work. It looks like there are a few other approaches to finding the "loaded" event for an OpenLayers map:

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2012-April/024858.html
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10671/register-event-loadend-on-layer

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks very much! the solution I've used is:
`vector_Layer.events.register("loadend", map, function(e) {  
          map.zoomToExtent(vector_Layer.getDataExtent());    
 });`